# Possible to make neomutt not automatically mark mail as read when opening an email?

Tags: neomutt

Can neomutt not mark mail as read when viewing?

Some email clients like thunderbird allow this.

Comment: there's duplicate question about the same: https://superuser.com/questions/1482939/possible-to-open-an-email-in-neomutt-without-marking-it-as-read
Would you mind marking it for deletion?

Comment: Done (odd, not sure must have asked twice by accident :/)

Comment: Also if the answer works for you, can  you mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that function *display-message* which opens the message in a pager marks the message as read automatically.

But you can create macro below for pager menu. Message would still be marked as read, but before exiting the pager, message will be marked as new. This would probably work only if you're using internal pager.

```
bind pager q noop # because mutt cannot unbind, but can bind noop.
macro pager q "<mark-as-new><exit>"
```

if you use recent version of neomutt you can also utilise `unbind` command

```
unbind pager q
macro pager q "<mark-as-new><exit>"
```

If you want to preserve `q` pager's binding for closing the pager and marking the message read, it's simple. There are two keys bound to the same function. Both `q` and `i` exits the pager. Just replace the `q` with `i` in the macro. And you're done.

select message `enter` to display it and:

- `q` exit pager and keep the message marked as read
- `i` exit pager and and mark the message as new